# SQL Server, Update with Counter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `AAA`.  When I order table `AAA` by `COLUMNI`, there is a `COLUMNJ` that needs to have the values "BINXXXXX"
where "BINXXXXX" needs to go up by 1 each time. For example, "BIN00001", then "BIN00002" etc.... all the way to the end.  It needs to do this when I order by `COLUMNI`.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COLUMNI, 
       COLUMNJ = 
'BIN' + RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COLUMNI ASC)),5) 
FROM dbo.AAA
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8424a/1/0)</kbd>

The `UPDATE` part is not clear for me, however here is an example using a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT AAA.*, 
           BIN_Num = 'BIN' 
                   + RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
                        ORDER  BY  COLUMNI ASC)), 5) 
         FROM   dbo.AAA) 
UPDATE CTE SET COLUMNJ = BIN_Num
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8424a/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: Does this need an Update statement too or?

Comment: I get this for some reason? Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.COLUMNJ = b.COLUMNJ
FROM dbo.AAA a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT COLUMNI, 
        COLUMNJ = 
'BIN' + RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY COLUMNI ASC)),5) 
FROM dbo.AAA)b
ON b.COLUMNI = a.COLUMNI
```

Borrowing from Tim's work above, this should update your table with the correct values.  Assuming that COLUMNI is unique, of course.

P.S.  I don't have enough rep to comment yet, so this is going in as an answer.

Comment: Voted you up, to get you some rep.